# How can I delete the duplicate objects inside Array when I fetch newsApi

Tags: javascript, json, api, object, dropdown

Hi I have some problem fetching specific information based on user choice.
I want to fetch newsAPI , inside array there are objects contain countries.
The user selects the country he wants by using dropdown, but there is an iterative country when I using map() it passes on all countries with duplicates, I tried to delete the duplicate, but it didn't work +
I used reduce() but it didn't work either.
Are there any tips and suggestions, maybe there is something I missed.

html:

```
<html>
 <div class="ui container" id="seachCountry"></div>
</html>
```

Script:

```
    <script>
    const apikey = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines/sources?category=sports&apiKey=b23fd6aac9c44682abb9580dae85d23f';
        async function getNews(){
            const response = await fetch(apikey);
            const data = await response.json();
            printCards(data)
        }
    
         function printCards(data) {
             const header = document.querySelector('#seachCountry');
                 //Inside  "header.innerHTMI",  I put map() function to pass all items but I couldn't prevent duplicates
                 header.innerHTML += `
                         <select class='ui fluid selection dropdown select' onchange="getCountry(this.value)">
                         <option>select the country</option>
                         ${data.sources.map( countryName => `<option>${countryName.country}</option>`)}
                         </select>`
                         // print all country name using map and dispaly it to user in dropdown WIHT deplicate country name
                     }
    
         async function getCountry(e){
             if ( e !== 'select the country'){
                //Another Fetch based on user choice
                const response = await fetch(`${apikey}&country=${e}`)
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data.sources)
    
    
                //It only shows the information of the country in which the user is interested
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =  data.sources.map(countryName =>
                    `<div class="ui container card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h4 class="header">${countryName.name}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="desc">${countryName.description}</div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="extra content">
                            <span>
                                <a href=${countryName.url} target="_blank" class="ui button btn">Read more</a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        </div>`)
             }
        }
        getNews()  
    </script>
```

[Look at this Picture to Clarify the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXPnK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the array to have only distinct values by using this function:

```js
source.filter((item, index) => source.indexOf(item) === index);
```

So, in your case, where you are mapping to a list of `option`s, it will be something like this:

```
function printCards(data) {
        const header = document.querySelector('#seachCountry');
        const countries = data.sources.map(cn => cn.country);
        const distinctCountries = countries.filter((country, index) => countries.indexOf(country) === index);

        header.innerHTML += `
                        <select class='ui fluid selection dropdown select' onchange="getCountry(this.value)">
                        <option>select the country</option>
                        ${distinctCountries.map(country => `<option>${country}</option>`)}
                        </select>`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: I've edited with a better description. Hope it helps.

Comment: You are really amazing, I've been trying to solve this code for four days,  now it really working Thank you, it makes more sense now.